# Asp.Net MVC signal R chat messages saved in a document db or Azure table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr, azure-table-storage

A Sql Server DB in Azure seems inefficient and expensive if the chat messages blow up my db with lots of data when users chat with each other.

Is there a better Azure solution where I can still save data associated with the message (ex. from id, to id, timestamp, etc).

Being unfamiliar with Document DB and Azure Tables, what's the difference and would one of these be a good solution? Or is there a better solution? Maybe Sql Azure Federations?

Currently I use a blob for storing images, but that doesn't seem like a good solution for chat messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Tables are nice and cheap. It'll allow you to search by partition and ID within partition - everything else is not indexed and can't be searched through easily. If you only need to get your chats retrieved by user/date - that can work nicely.

Cosmos DB is a lot more flexible than Azure Tables but a lot more expensive with a lot more hidden costs - like performance as a cost. And having to pay per collection, even if you don't use it.

Comment: maybe you can advise...This is a typical social site like Match or OkCupid, I need a page where previous messages can be seen with the users pics and time stamps and the last message. Then if clicked on a previous message I can pull up another page where the last ~6 messages are there and new messages can be created. Additionally if, from the profile page, a user clicks on the chat button then a small chat window opens to chat with that user and maybe the last 1-2 messages will be there as well

Comment: I see from your comments that if I just want to bring up chats from a previous user, tables will work nicely, but what about the page where I need to show chats from say the last 6-10 users!? Is there a way I can query the table for all messages from me (id) and then sort by unique id (id of the user I sent the message too) and date?

Comment: I'd store chat metadata (like who talking to whom and when, etc.) in a SQL database and also keep a GUID of the chat in SQL, but the actual text of a chat stored in Azure Table. This way you can search by your metadata and show last X chats/messages, but keep the data in tables.

Comment: Same principle applied - you can store the actual chats in Azure Blobs to that matter - as long as you can get ID from SQL

Comment: but as per your recommendation, wouldn't I then be storing a id and some other meta data for each and every chat message? Wouldn't this lead to a blow up of my database as well? Which is what I'd like to avoid! I mean, if I'm going to store that is Sql Server, then why not just store another ~100 bytes or so? Chat messages are all fairly short and I can limit them if I want

Comment: I'm talking about chats, not individual messages. Messages go to Tables, information about chats go to SQL. Choose where to put what according to your needs

Comment: I understand, I think! Metadata in Sql Server and message content in a Azure table or blob, but wouldn't this potentially lead to a blow up of a db as well?

Comment: Potentially. I don't know. Depends what you decide to store in SQL and how many chats you will have. But if you have enough chats to worry about, you will have enough money to cover storage expenses, otherwise it serves no purpose.

Comment: well, I can say the metadata I would store would be a couple of ids, date time stamp, id to the Azure table, maybe one or two other things. But I guess you have to expect all scenarios, including the one where you end up having millions of users and billions of chat messages to store.

Comment: Millions of users is a nice problem to have. If you have this problem - you'll have resources to re-write the storage. Don't overthink it.

Comment: one last question...Having never used Azure Tables, can I query and filter by the entity properties. ex. if the entity I save has a date, from id, to id, etc. ? Just like I would sql server data but doing it all in the Azure table? or can I only query an Azure table by id? Or what about another solution where I create a table partition for each user? would that be a good solution or too expensive in the long run?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities

Comment: I see, so it's by partition key then row key. Too bad there isn't a third key, that would solve lots of issues.